# Логирование в контейнерах docker

Tags: linux, debian, логирование, docker

Здравствуйте!

Имею `Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638` и вопрос по нему: Возможно ли заставить контейнер лить логи в гипервизор **без** установки доп. утилит и прочих контейнеров? Ну то есть у меня есть **debian**, на нём стоит **docker-engine** в котором есть некий **container**, так вот я хочу чтоб этот контейнер отдавал свои логи в rsyslog который установлен на debian, безо всяких костылей, утилит и иже с ними? То есть, когда я читаю лог `/var/log/daemon.log` в debian, я хочу видеть что-то типа:

```
Sep 10 19:49:25 debian container1[701]: Hello Sat Sep 10 14:49:25 UTC 2016
Sep 10 19:49:26 debian container2[702]: Hello Sat Sep 10 14:49:26 UTC 2016
Sep 10 19:49:27 debian container3[703]: Hello Sat Sep 10 14:49:27 UTC 2016
Sep 10 19:49:28 debian container4[704]: Hello Sat Sep 10 14:49:28 UTC 2016
Sep 10 19:49:29 debian containerN[705]: Hello Sat Sep 10 14:49:29 UTC 2016
Sep 10 19:49:30 debian containerN+6321465234123[666]: Hello Sat Sep 10 14:49:30 UTC 2016
```

Comment: Всё, нашёл, сори за беспокойство, просто до этого пробовал с отправкой на удалённый сервер, по этому протупил. Ответ: Запускать контейнер как-то так `docker run -t -d --log-driver=syslog --log-opt tag="{{.Name}}" ubuntu    /bin/bash -c 'while true; do echo "Hello $(date)"; sleep 1; done'` RTFM: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/

Comment: Хмм, странно, но с alpine такой фокус не проходит... :( Точнее с `echo` работает, но демон запущенный в контейнере продолжает писать лог в него :(